# AmbiguousMatchException when selecting from DbContext

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, ambiguous

I've seen a lot of questions about how to debug an AmbiguousMatchException encountered when updating or adding a record to a context, or when there are multiple overloads to a method, but I've found nothing so far about issues found when *selecting* from a context.

Suppose this is my class:

```
public class Foo
{
    public decimal IdNumber {get; set;}

    //...
}
```

And the mapping and context:

```
public class FoosMapping : EntityTypeConfigurationBase /*custom class*/, IEntityTypeConfiguration<Foo>
{
    public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<Foo> builder)
    {
        //Table
        builder.ToTable("Foos");

        //Key
        builder.HasKey(key => new {key.IdNumber}).HasName("FoosPk");

        //Fields
        PropertyBuilder<decimal> idField = builder.Property(x => x.IdNumber);
        idField.HasColumnName("IdNumber");
        if (this.ActiveProvider.IndexOf("SqlServer", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase) >= 0)
            idField.HasColumnType("numeric(6,0)");
        //...
    }
}
/***************************************************************************/
public class FooContext
{
    public DbSet<Foo> Foos {get; set;}

    //...
}
```

Now, I have a reader class that's supposed to pick one `Foo` based on its `IdNumber`. This should be doable with a straightforward call in the reader to `this.Context.Foos.SingleOrDefault()`, but instead it started giving me an AmbiguousMatchException. I even broke it out like this...

```
20: Foo[] foos = this.Context.Foos.ToArray();
21: Foo result = foos.SingleOrDefault(x => x.IdNumber == idNumber);
```

...and the exception appears when initializing **the array variable.** The text `Foos` is only found in the three classes mentioned above, plus a writer class and an adapter class. The `Foo` class is only referenced in those three files and an Autofac binding.

Is my problem the `idField` in the mapping, the fact that the DB table is also called `"Foos"`, or something else?

**EDIT:** The stack trace on the exception:

```
"   at System.RuntimeType.GetMethodImpl(String name, BindingFlags bindingAttr, Binder binder, CallingConventions callConv, Type[] types, ParameterModifier[] modifiers)"
```

The top of the call stack:

```
System.Core.dll!System.Linq.Buffer<MyProject.Data.Foo>.Buffer(System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<MyProject.Data.Foo> source)

System.Core.dll!System.Linq.Enumerable.ToArray<MyProject.Data.Foo>(System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<MyProject.Data.Foo> source)

> MyProject.Entity.dll!MyProject.Entity.Readers.FooReader.Read(decimal idNumber) Line 20
```

Comment: How about posting the exception stack? If one is to help you troubleshoot an exception, one needs to see details about the exception.

Comment: Can you call `ToList()` to Foo `DbContext`?

Comment: Have you checked your DB? Is the column `IdNumber` defined as PRIMARY KEY in the DB too? (using `decimal` typed values as key looks kind of suspicious to me, IIRC that is not supported in MS SQL Server, or at least must be of scale 0)... And also, are you sure that there are no duplicate `IdNumber` values in your DB?

Comment: @GonzaloLorieto: `ToList()` instead of `ToArray()` raises the same exception.

Comment: @bassfader: I've updated the mapping sample with more information from my live code regarding what the context does in SQL server. Regarding the DB side, IdNumber is indeed the primary key (NUMERIC(6,0)), and the table is actually empty at the moment.

Comment: **UPDATE:** It looks like the exception is coming from the **DbContext!**

Comment: It would be good if you can reproduce the issue in a clean project with just code from the post. Then you either will find the problem is your actual code, or you can update the post with the repro code (e.g. [mcve]) and we can take a look at it. Don't forget to include the exact EF Core version and the database provider used - you might be hitting some EFC bug, which is not so unusual. Still this is not an exception which happens normally, so repro is a must.

Answer (score 0):

For future users encountering similar problems and for whom other solutions aren't working, this issue was due to a new version of EF Core being installed, which was not playing well with our existing dependency injection framework. The Powers-That-Be decided to roll back to an older EF Core version for the time being, and everything works now.